# NPE on POST form submit multipart/form-data

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am using Jsps/Servlets to allow users to upload images (as outlined here: [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet#answer-2424824))

Ordinarily everything works ok (I have the `MultipartConfig` annotation on the appropriate servlet).

I got one case where a `NullPointerException` was thrown when trying to retrieve the part from the `HttpServletRequest`: `request.getPart()`.

According to the docs, this happens when the `request` doesn't contain the "requested part" (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart(java.lang.String)).

So, the only way I could recreate this issue was manipulating the html (via my browser's html editing tool) and manually erasing the `name` attribute of the file `input` element (ie: changing the `name` to an empty string).

I find it very unlikely that this is what the user did to cause the exception to be thrown. Are there any other reasons that this error might have occurred? I'd like to figure out what the cause was.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
Relevant html: (uses bootstrap collapse to display file `input` element)
(The data attributes are for javascript - maybe something with the quotations is messing with the `name` attribute?)

```
<form role="form" action="/fileUploadServlet" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data"
data-min-length='${minLength}' 
data-max-length='${maxLength}'
data-msg="${valMsg}"
data-size="${maxSize}">
    <a href="#input_collapse" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">
         Upload File
    </a>
    <span class="collapse" id="input_collapse">
         <input type="file" name="someFile" id="some_file">
    </span>
    ...[other form fields]
</form>
```

Relevant Servlet code: (calling `getSubmittedFileName()` throws the `NPE`)

```
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 1024*1024*5)
public class FileUploadServlet
{
...
try {
     Part filePart = req.getPart("someFile");
     ...filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
```

Comment: And where is your code? Do you expect us to have a crystal ball, or some magic sense to be able to "debug" your code without having it?

Comment: Added code to the question.

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: In which scenario does the issue occur and could you post the issue details along with your servlet code?

Comment: Hey, the issue occurs when the user submits the form. The servlet code above is the first thing that is checked and it throws the `NPE` (meaning the rest of the fields that are entered aren't relevant)...Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by some javascript validation that I had set up.

Specifically: on form submit, checking file size, on Internet Explorer, causes NPE mentioned in the question.

The javascript

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
    if ($("#some_file").files[0]) {
    ...
    }
});
```

I don't know why this happens. 
It doesn't happen in Firefox.
To fix this, I checked for validity upon `change` of the element rather than on form submit.

This isn't an ideal solution. I'm still trying to find out why this caused the error on Internet Explorer.